# Is there a way to show that $x^2=1$ is the only solution of $x^2+3=k^2$ for $x,k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question i'm trying to solve is: The sum of all natural numbers a such that $a^2-16a+67$ is a perfect square is (a)10, (b)12, (c)16, (4)22.

$a^2-16a+67$

= $a^2-16a+64+3$

=$(a-8)^2+3$

This is a perfect square when $(a-8)^2=1$ and so $a=7,9$

So the answer is $7+9 = 16$, which agrees with the answer given .

But i don't know how to show that these are the only possible values of a, or rather that $x^2=1$ is the only solution for this $x^2+3=k^2$ is the only value that works, can i get any tips/directions? Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: It’s $(k+x)(k-x)=3$

Comment: Also $x^2<x^2+3\leq (x+1)^2$ for $x\geq 1$.

Comment: $k=x+h$ then $k^2=x^2+2hx+h^2$ then $2hx+h^2=3$ Integer solutions for this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**here is a hint:**

It’s $k^2-x^2=(k+x)(k-x)=3$

Comment: I like your answers.

Comment: +1. I couldn't resist posting a different A.

Answer (score 2):

If $k,x \in \Bbb N$ and $3=k^2-x^2$

then $k^2>x^2\,$ so $k>x\,$ so $k\ge x+1\,$ so $k^2\ge (x+1)^2$

so $3=k^2-x^2\ge (x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$

so $3\ge 2x+1.$

Comment: Whenever you have a strict inequality $k>x$ between integers $k,x$ you can increase the information-content of it by "sharpening" it to $k\ge x+1.$

Comment: I like yours too ($+1$); I think it's similar to the comment above by rtybase